# How to type ASCII 145/146 (quotes) in vim?

Tags: vim

Using vim 7.2.330 on a Ubuntu host from an XP host, I'm stuck at how to type/paste the following line in a text file:

```
include_once(‘/full/path/to/app’);
```

The document says it's important to use ASCII 145 and 146, but vim turns them into "<92><93>", and Nano turns them into ï¿½.

Note that I'm using a European keyboard layout, not the US layout.

Does someone know how to solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: ASCII doesn't *have* values 145 and 146. Additionally, this isn't actually programming-related.

Comment: 145 and 146 are not part of ASCII. They have their most significant bit set. What document?

Comment: OK, so where should I ask this question?

Comment: I mean those characters: www.handheld-basic.com/documentation/text/page_599.html

Answer (score 6):

Er, you should *not* be using the 2 types of special quotes for string quoting in PHP.

You should be typing

```
include_once('/full/path/to/app');
```

( That's ASCII character 39 )

> This is not what it says at the end of
>   this document:
>   www.wpbbpthemes.org/integration/
>   "beware some pasting of this code make
>   the ‘ character change, make sure it’s
>   the button left of the enter key on
>   your [US] keyboard"

No, you are misinterpreting it. Lots of software in windows, and varying keyboards, erroneously do "smart quotes". Word and Internet Explorer are such examples. As a result, copy-pasting from these applications results in the wrong type of character in your source code, often conflicting with the content-encoding the document is served as, which renders on the displaying browser as a silly Ä or similar character.

Do not use characters 145 and 146 in your PHP source, it is not necessary, **and** it won't work.

Also, Important to note, the authors of that page have **USED THE WRONG QUOTES IN THEIR EXAMPLES** and as such, **WILL NOT WORK AS STATED**.

Their statement with regard to "beware some pasting will make the character change" is bogusly incorrect, they have the incorrect character in their source, and as such, copy-pasting it at any time will not work.

Comment: This is not what it says at the end of this document: www.wpbbpthemes.org/integration/

"beware some pasting of this code make the ‘ character change, make sure it’s the button left of the enter key on your [US] keyboard"

Comment: Additionally, the dude says on his website: 'I wanted to contribute to the bbPress community but I’m not a coder.'. Summary: You should not listen to any advice he has regarding coding.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have to follow this document as it was pointed to me in getting those two applications to work together. I'll ask the author.

Comment: @overtherainbow - look at @Kent_Fredric's reputation--15.5k is far above the norm for Stack Overflow.  He knows what he's talking about.  You should trust him more than the author of the document you're reading.

Comment: Sure. I didn't doubt Kent's explanations.